# Top item for each top 5 group by record count (Access SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a single large table `Audit` with thousands of records of denied claims. Each one comes from a supplier and has a denial reason and a status. Only the `id` is unique.

```
id |      denial      |   supplier    | status
---|------------------|---------------|---------
 1 | Duplicate claim  | ACME          | Adjusted
 2 | Not authorized   | Umbrella Corp | Adjusted
 3 | Not authorized   | Stark Ind.    | Adjusted
 4 | Rec'd after due  | ACME          | Override
 5 | Duplicate claim  | Stark Ind.    | Adjusted
... etc
```

What I need is the top 5 denial reasons for "Adjusted" status claims by record count, and the top provider by record count for each of those denial reasons.

```
denial          | cnt_denial | top_supplier  | cnt_top_supplier
----------------|------------|---------------|-----------------
Not authorized  | 917        | Stark Ind.    | 351
Duplicate claim | 685        | Stark Ind.    | 195
Not in contract | 525        | ACME          | 216
Rec'd after due | 512        | Umbrella Corp | 500
Explosions      | 349        | ACME          | 231
```

I've tried lots of ways, mostly trying to adapt other somewhat similar solutions, but I'm overreaching my meager SQL knowledge here and getting frustrated. Several solutions I've tried do not work in MS Access (2010). I created two queries as a start, but I'm having trouble joining them in the way that I need.

This query returns exactly the denial reason data that I need:

```
SELECT TOP 5 denial, Count(*) AS cnt_denial
FROM Audit
GROUP BY status, denial
HAVING status="Adjusted"
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

And this query has a count of every denial/supplier grouping in the table. I'm not sure how to get the top supplier for each denial reason, which seems like it should be simple but I'm having trouble. EDIT: This is my primary problem. If I can just get the top single supplier for each denial reason I can figure out the join. I've tried using MAX but haven't succeeded yet. /EDIT

```
SELECT denial, supplier, Count(*) AS cnt_supplier
FROM Audit
GROUP BY denial, supplier, status
HAVING status="Adjusted"
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

I need a single query since I'll just be passing this from Excel via ADO. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Are ties in the denial/supplier ranking going to matter for you?

Comment: Currently, no... in the event of a tie, I just need a spot filled. It's for weekly reporting purposes only, and our report template only accommodates one top supplier each. We may eventually want to adjust that to Top 2 suppliers for each denial.

Comment: Side notes: `HAVING` without an aggregate function should be changed to a `WHERE` clause, and you don't need to include a constant-valued column inside a `GROUP BY` (might be optimized out, don't know).  Further, there's rarely a reason to exclude `GROUP BY`'d columns from the `SELECT`, since it usually makes the results mysterious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is perfectly valid Access SQL. It shouldn't require much tweaking if it isn't:

```
select
    d.denial,
    d.cnt_denial,
    ds.supplier as top_supplier,
    ds.cnt_supplier as cnt_top_supplier
from
    (
        select top 5 denial, count(*) as cnt_denial
        from Audit
        where status = 'Adjusted'
        group by denial
        order by count(*) desc
    ) d
    inner join
    (
        select denial, supplier, count(*) as cnt_supplier
        from Audit
        where status = 'Adjusted'
        group by denial, supplier
    ) ds
        on ds.denial = d.denial
where not exists (
    select 1
    from Audit as a2
    where a2.status = 'Adjusted'
        and a2.denial = ds.denial and a2.supplier <> ds.supplier
    group by a2.supplier
    having count(*) > ds.cnt_supplier
        /* or count(*) = ds.cnt_supplier and a2.supplier < ds.supplier -- tiebreaker */
)
order by d.cnt_denial desc, ds.supplier
```

By using the `top 5` it's grabbing only five rows regardless of ties. Then the top 1 per group is handled with a subquery and in that case you would include ties and potentially retrieve more than five rows in the final result. It's not too difficult to include ties at the denial level if you need that or to break ties and exclude them in the supplier ranking.

**EDIT:** I threw together some test data and the tie-breaking appears to work on SQL Server. http://rextester.com/ZEWJ43486

Comment: Thank you, this works!  It takes a minute or two to run, but the results are exactly what I'm looking for.  Note: The commented-out supplier tiebreaker you provided is returning far too many results per denial. I tried adjusting it to `count(*) > ds.cnt_supplier and t2.supplier < ds.supplier` but still got several suppliers for each denial.

Comment: @PhiZeroth Any chance you can share the results? I posted a link to some testing that I did.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! I realized the commented code was in addition to, not a replacement of, the `having` criteria. Tie-breaking is working perfectly now. Thanks so much for taking the time to help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've done all the hard work.

One solution is to test for denial reason inclusion in your second query

Save your first query as **qTop5Reasons**

```
SELECT TOP 5 denial, Count(*) AS cnt_denial
FROM Audit
GROUP BY status, denial
HAVING status="Adjusted"
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

The modify your second query to limit the results based on the reasons in that query:

```
SELECT Audit.denial, Audit.supplier, Count(*) AS cnt_supplier
FROM Audit
WHERE (Audit.denial In (SELECT denial FROM qTop5Reasons))
GROUP BY Audit.denial, Audit.supplier, Audit.status
HAVING (((Audit.[status])="Adjusted"))
ORDER BY Count(*) DESC;
```

Comment: fyi, since there's no aggregate function, the criteria in the `HAVING` clause should move to the `WHERE` clause, and if you include the `Status` field in the `SELECT` clause of qTop5, you can join on the `denial` and `status` fields in your 2nd query instead of repeating the limit on the `status` field.

Comment: This still doesn't narrow down to the top 1 provider per denial reason, which is my main problem. Do you know how to adjust the second query to show only the top provider for each denial?

Answer (score 0):

You should try Inner join . Try this

```
SELECT A.DENIAL, A.Cnt_Denial,B.Supplier as TOP_SUPPLIER, B.Cnt_supplier as           
TOP_CNT_SUPPLIER
FROM 
(SELECT TOP 5 denial, Count(*) AS cnt_denial
 FROM Audit
 GROUP BY status, denial
 HAVING status="Adjusted"
 ORDER BY Count(*) DESC) AS A INNER JOIN 
 (SELECT TOP 5 denial, supplier, Count(*) AS cnt_supplier
 FROM Audit
 GROUP BY denial, supplier, status
 HAVING status="Adjusted"
 ORDER BY Count(*) DESC) AS B
 ON A.DENIAL = B.DENIAL
```

Comment: This returns every supplier for the top 5 denial reasons.  I need only the top 1 supplier, but simply adding `TOP 1` to the last select returns nothing. The result should be only 5 rows.